# Is the "Open Recent" menu functionality available to me?

Tags: macos, appkit, nsmenu, recent-file-list

In AppKit, the "Open Recent" menu has a lot of useful functionality, like the ability to display relevant folders for context, but only when needed.

Is there a way to get access to this functionality myself?  I want to display a list of folders in a window, and I'd like to include paths for identically named folders, using the same algorithm as Apple.

Is there any way to do that, without implementing it myself from scratch?

Comment: You get that functionality when creating a document based project.

Comment: vadian: Yes, I know that.

Comment: Then what is the question, as I doubt anyone is going to rewrite the functionality for you.

Comment: Sorry, I thought I made that clear: "I want to display a list of folders *in a window*".  The automatic document-based functionality you refer to only seems to exist in one place: a menu item with `hasSubmenu` which is directly beneath the `#selector(openDocument)` item.

Answer (score 1):

See `- [NSDocumentController recent​Document​URLs]` https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsdocumentcontroller/1514976-recentdocumenturls